# How to port C++ to swf with Alchemy?

Tags: c++, flash

Alchemy allows users to compile C and C++ code that is targeted to run on the open source ActionScript Virtual Machine (AVM2). While this idea seems really promising has anyone had success with this - if so are there examples?

I was wanting to convert some old DOS programs to SWF so they could be ran in the browser.

Comment: From the website: "Alchemy is primarily intended to be used with C/C++ libraries that have few operating system dependencies. [...]". HTH.

Comment: Thank You. I guess that makes sense otherwise it would have to mimic an OS to run a C++ app.

Comment: An example of a C++ game that was ported is Doom. Here is an interview with the developer http://www.peterelst.com/blog/2008/12/18/porting-doom-to-flash-interview-with-mike-welsh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most old DOS code isn't very portable, so running it on anything but DOS will take considerable work. Quite a bit of it makes direct use of DOS interrupts, absolute locations in the memory map, and so on. Getting these to run under AVM2 would basically not just require a C compiler, but a full emulation of MS-DOS, a BIOS, and PC hardware.

Comment: The DOS Code was very standard C++ written in Borland C++ for DOS back in circa 1996 by me. It uses standard C++ libraries.

Comment: If it's really *standard* so about its only dependence on the OS is for standard I/O, then porting it should be about as easy it it gets.